# Lazily importing from submodules within __init__.py in a way static code analysis tools can understand

Tags: python, lazy-loading, python-import

So, let's imagine I've got a python package of library code with 20 logically-separated modules, and I want to select 1 or 2 classes from each of them for the package's public api. Rather than forcing users to import these classes from the modules directly, I want to make them available directly from the package's namespace, within `__init__.py`.

But I don't want everything to be loaded eagerly every time, since loading all 20 modules whenever someone tries to access just one class from a single one is a huge waste (some of them contain their own expensive imports), so I implement a module-level `__getattr__()` as per https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/ and use importlib within it to load the module of a given class whenever someone tries to import that class.

This is a relatively clean solution, but the part that makes it a nightmare is that this absolutely kills static code analysis tools like Jedi or PyCharm. Autocompletion and on-cursor-hover docstrings are a huge deal to me, since they massively increase productivity, so I don't want to write library code that IDEs cannot understand.

I could write typing stubs, but that would add more burden of maintenance, when really I already have all my code type-annotated and with docstrings inline. It's not a great solution.

Does anyone have an idea how else I could go about this? I'm hoping there's some clever way around this that I just haven't thought about.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but incase anyone else comes across this the solution I have that works with VSCode + Sublime static analysis is as follows:

```
import importlib
import pathlib

# this is used instead of typing.TYPE_CHECKING as it avoids needing to import
# the typing module at all
_typing = False
if _typing:
    import sub_package
del _typing

def __getattr__(name: str):
    current_file = pathlib.Path(__file__)
    current_directory = current_file.parent
    for path in current_directory.iterdir():
        if path.stem != name:
            continue

        return importlib.import_module(f"{__package__}.{name}")

    raise AttributeError(f"{__package__} has no attribute named: {name}")


__all__ = ("sub_package",)
```

I think what was missing from OP was exposing the `__all__` variable

Comment: Can you please explain how `_typing` helps with the missing type annotations? How does defining a variable and than just deleting it does anything? In the comment, you mentioned that it replaces `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`, but `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` isn't mentioned in the lined pep-0562.

Comment: Static analysis (at least the ones in VSCode and Sublime) doesn't build up it's database from active code, afaik this is by design considering the `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` implementation in the typing codebase: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING
This allows a virtual import of the modules which type checkers/static analysis will read without importing them until needed.
Creating a bool variable is minimal overhead, no import and deleting it keeps the namespace clean.
As mentioned, I think the main thing missing for OP's example was exposing using `__all__`